# Can't open Swift Guided Tour Playground

Tags: xcode, swift

When I try to open the Swift Guided Tour playground from Apple's e-Book, it says "the document can't be opened because it is from a newer version of Xcode. As far as I can tell, I'm using the newest non-Beta version, and I'm not working with Swift 2.0 yet, still learning the first version. Have all the playgrounds been updated to work with Xcode 7 Beta or something? I'm using Xcode 6.3.2, just in case that isn't actually the newest version.

Comment: It depends where you downloaded the Apple e-Book. From the beta tab or the release one?

Comment: I downloaded the e-Book off of iBooks, so I would think that would be the release one.

Comment: Ok, all I did was delete it off of my computer and re-download it, but suddenly it started working. What happened?

Answer (score 3):

I got the same issue with xcode 6.3.2.
I got the issue when I downloaded it via ibook link. Once I downloaded it via we, it worked.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH2-ID1

My previous version was playground version='1.0' and the new one also same. But it includes lots of new libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I got that problem too, and finally i open it OK, that just problem with where you download your .playground file:

@Xcelleratr Download your file here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html

It will be OK my friend :)

Comment: Normally, Link only answers are discouraged, but since this is what the OP is looking for, Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: The link it has a file to download man it is not Link-only answers ! i answered his question in my comment already: "that just problem with where you download your .playground file".

Answer (score 0):

works for Xcode version:

`Version 6.3.2 (6D2105)`

`Version 7.0 beta (7A120f)`

Im guessing it was corrupted could check it by:
`Right clicking on the playground file` > `show package contents` > `open contents.xcplayground` in a text editor like sublime and look for `playground version='3.0'` near the top

If this is any higher it will pop up with the error you seen.

Comment: It shows up with playground version = '6.0' How did that happen?

Comment: Thats really odd!?! If you set it to 3.0 does it open ok?

Comment: Well that's the weirder thing, I deleted it and redownloaded it and now its working, even despite the version being written wrong.

Comment: Although I tried that and instead it came up with this error Line 2: AttValue: " or ' expected
Line 2: attributes construct error
Line 2: Couldn't find end of Start Tag playground

Comment: sorry ment to say make line 2: <playground version='3.0' sdk='macosx' allows-reset='YES'>

Comment: line 2 looks completely different from that. Here's what it looks like: <playground version=‘6.0’ target-platform='osx' allows-reset='true' display-mode='rendered'>

Comment: It saying things like "target-platform" instead of sdk and having an extra "display-mode" setting makes me thing we might be looking at two different versions or something.

Comment: I was just downloading it from https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.playground.zip even when I open it from the ebook I still dont get that. Weird that we are getting different files

Comment: I downloaded the one from the first link you just put in the comments, and that one crashes X-code for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone stumbled upon this problem, here is what happened to me:

1. Download from [guided tour page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH2-ID1).
2. Save it with .zip extension instead of .playground, as seen in this picture:

[image]

3. Double click the downloaded file, it will unzip it and you'll get your actual GuidedTour.playground file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So if you have a playground file and it only opens xcode and not a guided playground, right click the playground fle and show package contents, then go to contents.xcplayground and rightclick and open with text editor.

I had to change this line...

display-mode='raw'>

to ....

display-mode='rendered'>

then save and when you go back and open the playground it should be ok now.